# Hartshorne II Example 7.6.2:The restriction of a sheaf of modules to a fibre.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

In this example, $Q=\mathbb P^1\times\mathbb P^1$, and set $p_1,p_2$ be the projections of $Q$ as a fibered product. Then for any $a,b\in \mathbb Z$, we can consider the sheaf on $Q$: $\mathscr L=p_1^*(O(a))\otimes p_2^*(O(b))$. Then he says"by restricting to a fibre of the product $\mathbb P^1\times \mathbb P^1$" we know $\mathscr L$ is not generated by global sections.

I'm confused about how to do restriction. I know we can pick a point(say $P$) at the second coordinate of $Q$. Then the fibre of $P$ in $Q$ is $p_2^{-1}(P)=\mathbb P^1\times_{\operatorname{Spec}k}\operatorname{Spec}k=\mathbb P^1$, and we have a canonical embedding $f:p_2^{-1}(P)\to \mathbb P^1\times \mathbb P^1$. But  how to do restriction on $\mathscr L$ to this fiber? Does he mean the sheaf $f^*(\mathscr L)$? But then how to know $\mathscr L$ itself cannot be generated by its global sections? Could you provide any help? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This statement (that $\mathscr L$ is not generated by global sections) is under the additional assumption that either $a < 0$ or $b < 0$. First of all yes, the restriction of a sheaf $F$ to a closed subscheme $f:Y \to X$ is the pullback $f^*(F)$. In general, $\mathscr L$ restricts to $\mathcal O_{\mathbb P^1}(b)$ when restricted to a fiber of the first projection, and to $\mathcal O_{\mathbb P^1}(a)$ when restricted to a fiber of the second projection.

So if either $a$ or $b$ is negative, there is a closed subscheme $Y\subset Q$ along which $\mathscr L|_Y$ has no global sections, hence $\mathscr L$ has no global sections over $Q$ and cannot be globally generated.